# Dart Flutter searching string with accents

Tags: string, flutter, search, dart, diacritics

I'm implementing a flutter app, in French, where I have to make a search in a large list of strings. I did a first app in swift on IOS  using the very same data, but in dart/flutter I find that I miss quite a lot of good match (compared to IOS/Swift version) for accentuated words. The data comes from different sources and has been entered manually on different OS (windows, macOS, etc).

I have found that a normalize function exists in JS and that it might be a solution, but I haven't found such a function in Dart.

Any solution or recommendation would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `RegExp`?